# Beginner trying to use \usepackage[all]{xy} command

Tags: packages, xy-pic

I've been using `LaTeX` for a while now (all throughout my undergrad in math) but now my graduate professors/coauthors are sharing `LaTeX` files with me via dropbox and I can't get them to compile in my editor TeXstudio run on my Mac (OS:X 10.11.6).

The main error I'm getting is from the line `\usepackage[all]{xy}`, with the error being "File 'xy.sty'not found \oddsidemargin".

I've had no problem installing other packages, (like `comment.sty`, or `xcolor.sty`) but those were all single packages that I just included in the same file as whatever .tex file I was working on.

However, my understanding is that when someone uses the line `\usepackage[all]{xy}`, they are taking a lot of .sty files from the directory xypics (is this right?). I've downloaded the xypics file and included it in the same directory as my .tex file, but I'm still getting the same error, "File 'xy.sty' not found \oddsidemargin".

Comment: you shouldn't have to install xy by hand from ctan, you should be able to get it by updating the package in your miktex or texlive installation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your comment! How would I do that? I've tried looking at the package installer from TeXstudio, but there's nothing there (xy is not a recognized package).

Comment: texstudio are you using miktex or texlive?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I think it's called MacTex, which is a redistribution of TeX Live for macOS

Comment: then you can use `tlmgr install xypic` or the equivalent in the mactex texlive utility which I think the mactex version has I don't have a mac.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm sorry for all of the basic questions I'm asking. Where can I find the editor so that I can use this command? When I use the search bar on my mac I can't find the editor. Would it be somewhere in the TeXstudio package?